# d3.js NVD3 trigger tooltip manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a bar graph and a table that are made using the same data. I want to make it so that when I hover over a cell in the table, the corresponding bar in the graph is highlighted and shows the tooltip. I'm having a difficult time finding a way to manually trigger the tooltip to show up. .trigger('hover'), .trigger('mouseover'), and .trigger('mouseenter') on the correct bar don't do it.

How can I manually trigger the tooltip to show up for a specific bar in my bar graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually show a tooltip by doing:

```
nv.tooltip.show([200, 400], '<p>Your content goes here</p>');
```

Then to hide the tooltip do:

```
nv.tooltip.cleanup();
```

I only found out how to do it by searching the code. I couldn't find any documentation.

Here's an advanced example for the situation I needed to solve (showing a tooltip on a legend label, using jQuery):

```
$("#chart svg .nv-series .nv-legend-text").each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).hover(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        // data is my array of objects passed into d3.select("#chart svg").datum(data)
        nv.tooltip.show([offset.left, offset.top], '<p>' + data[i].longLabel + '</p>');
    }, function() {
        nv.tooltip.cleanup();
    });
});
```

To solve your situation, you could probably do something similar, except select for the individual bar elements.

Comment: Yes, this gets me going in the right direction. I was hoping that I could just get it to create the correct tooltip based on the bar in the graph, but I can get the same information to appear manually this way. Just requires a bit more code than I was hoping for.

Comment: @HankScorpio that makes sense given that the solution uses an undocumented method. Though I'm not sure why someone would downvote an answer once it didn't work in a new version; however this solution will still work for the version of nvd3 that OP is using.

Comment: As I see it (and I also read this somewhere, can't remember where), stackoverflow is a knowledge repository. It's the go-to place for coding solutions and to get more in-depth knowledge. High votes for an obsolete answer are misleading. The answer worked before, but it no longer works (through no fault of yours) so its value is lower. If you (or the OP) were to add which version(s) this works for then there would still be some value in this answer, but that info isn't here. Can you add it?

Comment: @HankScorpio yes, i agree, but I usually downvotes are reserved for [bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers). The version is implicit to the time the question is asked. At the current moment I'm too busy to investigate even if this answer doesn't work in new versions of nvd3 and I don't have time to investigate an answer for newer versions. Somone else is obviously free to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I show/hide/move the tooltip for my custom chart (based on other nvd3 charts) for version 1.8.1:

```
tooltip = nv.models.tooltip();

// config...
tooltip
    .headerEnabled(false)
    .duration(0)
    .valueFormatter(function(d, i) {
        return packedBubble.valueFormat()(d, i);
    });
```

...

```
packedBubble.dispatch.on('elementMouseover.tooltip', function(evt) {
    evt['series'] = {
        key: evt.data.name,
        value: evt.data,
        color: evt.color
    };

    tooltip.data(evt).hidden(false);
});

packedBubble.dispatch.on('elementMouseout.tooltip', function(evt) {
    tooltip.hidden(true);
});

packedBubble.dispatch.on('elementMousemove.tooltip', function(evt) {
    tooltip.position({ top: d3.event.pageY, left: d3.event.pageX })();
});
```

So just use `chart.tooltip` if you're outside the chart to manipulate it in the same way with hidden()/position()/data().